# How to correctly fill a BOM with split connectors

Tags: connector, documentation, bom

I have to prepare the documentation for production.
In our board we use a specific female header with 6 positions.
Long story short, the buyer guys told me we will buy a 64-way connector and then it will be split up:

https://www.mouser.it/ProductDetail/Mill-Max/315-43-164-41-001000?qs=FG09h9tFCuBGctf6cn%2FLOw%3D%3D

Let's say I have the following BOM:

```
Ref      Q.ty     Mft.       Value
R1, R2   2                   1k 1% 1/10W
...
J1       1        Mill-Max   315-43-164-41-001000
...
```

I'm not sure how to address this scenario.
The actual p/n to buy is correct (`315-43-164-41-001000`) but the quantity needed depends on the point of view:

- for the PCB is ONE item (but not the whole strip)
- for the buyer guys should be something like 64/6 (in order to buy the needed quantity for a given amount of boards)

How would you handle this scenario in order to make a clear and understandable documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Don't.

   A 6-pin version exists: 315-43-106-41-001000, though it seems not stocked by Mouser.  Digi-Key and others have it.

   Eliminates confusion, no assembler in the world will ask what you want done with this, or complain that it's a gross mismatch to footprint, etc.  Maybe even automatic assembly can be done (if one happens to have a machine to grip and place those things..).
2. Put copious notes on it.

   If you're lucky, they'll read the notes (comment, description, extra column; text on the assembly drawings; txt file in the package; etc.) and figure it out.  There is no standard for this, write it in however you like.  Downside: all the extra noise may confuse the assembler, and English text might be ignored by overseas assemblers (particularly budget services that offer *their proto process* and nothing more).
3. Provide it in a separate material list.

   This is probably the least effective (read: most likely to get boards without connectors soldered into them), but it's a format where "rate" materials are standard (i.e., length of wire, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

Digi-Key offers value added parts that are exactly what you want: standard headers split down to the length you want. They show as 0 stock level but as long as it says “value added item”, the stock level is not relevant. They almost always have stock of the “raw material” - long strips - to feed into their machines.

Answer (score 5):

Assign two part numbers:

1. Incoming, off-the-shelf part, uncut
2. Cut part, ready for installation on board; prince includes the labor cost of cutting it; its BOM has a single line item: the first part number

The BOM for the assembly has the second part number.